# Полное сохранение страниц для отладки

Tags: веб-программирование

Доброго всем времени суток господа. Соскучился по всем )

Вопрос, ближе к руткоду, но там тонкость вопроса не поймут, просьба модерам понять и простить.

Иногда из инета сохраняю страницы, что бы выковырять некоторый код, и принять на вооружение. Дело конечно в JS и JQ. Одно дело просто кнопки в браузере выучить и уметь, другое уже в сохраненной странице копаться, да и вообще запустить ее локально. 99% может и сохраниться, а вот наметанный глаз программера может подметить 1% не_сохраненного/не_функционирующего. Хочу спросить у всех кто занимается JS и JQ, чем пользуетесь, и пользуетесь ли вообще?

Comment: httrack? Но смысла грабать страницы не вижу.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Teleport Pro](http://rutracker.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1540693) - грабит все что надо и не надо

Comment: Оно самое. И на будущее, и даже под мою задачу подошло

Comment: [Версия посвежее][1]

   [1]:http://nnm-club.me/forum/viewtopic.php?t=683108